# Android layout creation help needed

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to make a "gamepad" with WASD and arrows in each side like this:
[image: layout]

but instead of the arrow pad being below WASD i want them to be in the same "line" with the WASD in the left and arrows in the right

can someone help me with this (i'm not posting my code since it's garbage and not even close to the solution, it's just to illustrate what i'm trying to do)?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menubg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="W" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="S" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="D" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="↑" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="←" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="↓" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="→" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So many ways, best for us to do is fix your existing layout. Don't nee code, just the xml layout file.

Comment: @weston well i didn't make the xml to create the solution it was just for illustration but i've added it into the post if you think it'll help

Comment: Relative layout will do what you like. So will others.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It's not that I didn't try relative layout or anything else it's just that I failed to do so the way I needed it to be.

Comment: You could also use a GridLayout (2 rows of 6 columns)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/keypad"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="W" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="9" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="A" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="S" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="D" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="↑" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="9" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="←" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="↓" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="→" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works great but is there a way to put another layout below the WASD/arrows that will be horizontal? because just placing another layout causes it to be to the right of the arrow group